# Ubuntu PHP - Could not startup

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I have a weird problem. The sites on the server are running fine, but when I type "php" in the command line it says "Could not startup.". Obviously "php -v" doesn't show anything either.

Your help will be much appreciated, thanks!

PS: What's the difference between the apache2 php.ini file and the cli php.ini?

EDIT: Thank you very much for helping me diagnose the problem everyone! There was one line in the php.ini file `memory_limit = 32` and didn't have the unit specified so I changed it like so `memory_limit = 32M` and it fixed it for me.

Thanks!

Comment: CLI and Apache are different SAPIs, hence they have different ini files. There might be some extensions enabled in your php.ini for CLI that crash php. Disable them and reenable one by one. Or reinstall PHP.

Comment: Did you try to set `display_startup_errors` to `on` in CLI's php.ini to see whats happening?

Comment: Yes I tried display_startup_errors but it still shows the same message "Could not startup."

Comment: how was it installed? have u tried 'sudo apt-get install php5-dev'?

Comment: Try `php -n` and check http://serverfault.com/questions/301070/php-cli-error-could-not-startup please.

Comment: I have read the question before, it didn't help me. And the `php -n` command shows nothing

Comment: that's good. Try `php -nv` or `php -n --ini`. If any of these give output it's likely your php.ini is corrupted (like I suggested in my first comment already)

Comment: The output from `php -nv`:

`PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr  4 2014 01:30:04)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
`

The output from `php -n --ini`:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache2 php.ini is the php configuration loaded when you execute php program via webbrowser.

The cli php.ini  is the php configuration loaded when you execute php program via console.

**You can do further troubleshooting by enabling php error logging**

1)Edit cli php.ini

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log
```

2) save & restart php handler or Apache

3) `tail -f /var/log/php-errors.log`

4) Take new tab & execute `php` command

You can see exact errors in previous tab where you are taling the log.

Comment: I did as you told me and now it shows the following:

`[31-May-2014 09:56:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes       exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in Unknown on line 0`

what does it mean?

Comment: @Galanx In your cli php.ini change `memory_limit = 32` to `memory_limit = 32M`